# File not uploading to ibm cloud object storage using python getting an error

Tags: boto3, cloud-object-storage

So I was trying to upload a file to my bucket. here is the code for it :-

```
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config

cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',use_ssl=False,verify=False,
                       ibm_api_key_id='secret',
                       ibm_service_instance_id='secret',
                       config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                       endpoint_url='https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints')

try:
    res = cos.upload_file('C:/Users/avinamishra/Pictures/green.jpg','avi-test-bucket', 'green.jpg')
except Exception as e:
    print(Exception, e)
else:
    print('File Uploaded')
```

**Error : <class 'Exception'> Error when retrieving credentials from https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token: HttpCode(400) - Retrieval of tokens from server failed.
[Finished in 8.5s]**

Using docs from here - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-python

The documentation is probably out of date or I don't know. Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Please provide precise information about what exactly you tried and what error messages you get. Otherwise people will not be able to help you.

Comment: Updated more details in the post.